# want to access specific dictionary value from an url and getting key 0 error in python

Tags: python

I want to access the place value in the dictionary resent in the `URL`

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02

I wrote the below code but it is throwing an error key 0. I want to access some of the values like place, title, geometry from the `URL` and write it to `CSV` file.

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'

# download the json string
json_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

# de-serialize the string so that we can work with it
j = json.loads(json_string)

names = [d['properties'] for d in j[0]['type']]

print names
```

I am new to python.

Comment: since you can call `print names` you are probably using python 2. Try using python 3 since it is currently better supported. Probably your error is related to a python 3 tutorial or package you are trying to use with python 2.

Answer (score 0):

`j` is a dictionary that has keys `['type', 'metadata', 'features', 'bbox']`, but not 0. You are probably looking for `j['features']`, not `j[0]['type']`, but then the value of `names` is a list of dictionaries, not *names*. I hypothesize that the JSON API of the site has changed since you (or whoever wrote the code) last used it.